Nginx Reverse proxy doesn't load my files
I have two services running in my docker, /app1 on 8080 and /app2 on 3000. I setup my nginx reverse proxy for the services on port 80.
In port 3000 (main server),
If I request http://localhost:3000/, I get my index.html with files. If I request http://localhost:3000/files, I get my files as a json which is perfect.
But in port 80 (nginx port),
When I inspect the page, I see these two names in network tab:

files with request URL as http://localhost/app2/files and response of this says


"failed to load response data: no content available because this request was redirected"


files/ with request URL as http://localhost/files. the above request was redirected to this request, which is not to be done.

Please find my config below and suggest me how to fix it :)
PS: The server works perfectly when I run it on main port (not the nginx proxy).
My nginx.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://app1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /app2/ {
        proxy_pass http://app2:3000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /app2/files/ {
        proxy_pass http://app2:3000/files/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}


ATM readers can only guess what the problem is. Enabling debug logging will likely point out that the url the proxied services are receiving, are not the urls you're expecting - if it does not please update the question to include relevant information. Generally please show (e.g. curl -I some/url) don't describe errors/behavior.
